# How to consume two typescript 0.9.5 interfaces that both describe a "get" function?

Tags: dojo, typescript

I made this example of what seems to be valid typescript (playground link and inline as well):
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20I1%20%7B%0A%09%09get(name%3A%20%22templatePath%22)%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09get(name%3A%20string)%3A%20any%3B%09%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20I2%20%7B%0A%09%09get(name%3A%20%22baseClass%22)%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09get(name%3A%20string)%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20I3%20extends%20I1%2C%20I2%20%7B%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20C3%20implements%20I3%20%7B%0A%09%09get(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09return%20name%3B%0A%09%09%7D%09%0A%7D

```
interface I1 {
        get(name: "templatePath"): string;
        get(name: string): any; 
}

interface I2 {
        get(name: "baseClass"): string;
        get(name: string): any;
}

interface I3 extends I1, I2 {

}

class C3 implements I3 {
        get(name: string) {
            return name;
        }   
}
```

And I get an error indication types of property 'get' are not identical in these two interfaces.  (1) I don't see how that matters and (2) I don't know how to get around this.

Specifically my interface looks like this:

```
interface IGotoPane extends dijit._WidgetBase, dijit._TemplatedMixin, dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin {
    inputCoordinates: dijit._Widget;
}
```

I've found that I can eliminate the compiler errors by re-declaring several methods:

```
interface I3 extends I1, I2 {
        get(name: string): any;     
}
```

Or in the case of my specific issue,

```
interface IGotoPane extends dijit._WidgetBase, dijit._TemplatedMixin, dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin {
    inputCoordinates: dijit._Widget;
    get(name: string): any;
    set(name: string, value: any, raiseChangeEvent?: boolean): void;
    set(values: Dojo.PropertiesMap): void;
    watch(prop: string, callback: Dojo.WatchCallback<any>): Dojo.WatchHandle;
}
```

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error about the properties needing to be identical is sort of common-sense -- what is the type of `I3.get` if left unspecified as in your first example? There isn't any notion of "merging" function types in TypeScript, so it isn't clear what exactly this would mean.

You can reason about simple cases, but it quickly becomes very confusing for nontrivial cases, for example:

```
interface I1 {
    foo(a: string, b: "y"): number;
    foo(a: string, b: string): any;
}

interface I2 {
    foo(a: "x", b: string): boolean;
    foo(a: string, b: string): any;
}

interface I3 extends I1, I2 {
}

var x: I3;
var y = x.foo('x', 'y'); // y: number? boolean? any?
```

The fix of explicitly declaring `get` in `I3` is the correct one. You can copy down the constant-specialized signatures if they apply in that case.

Comment: Thanks.  Your example is a good one and I can see the ambiguity in this case but in the case of "get" it seems obvious the specialized "get" should take precedence.  But there is no precedence and therefore I1.get2 and I2.get1 become ambiguous?  I'm not fully seeing the compiler problem but perhaps that's what you mean by being able to reason about the simple cases.

Comment: Not that my intuition has any relevance but to answer your question, I assumed I3 would take this shape: {
        get(name: "templatePath"): string;
        get(name: "baseClass"): string;
        get(name: string): any;
}

So in your example I would assume the return type to be a number ("y" beats "x"):
interface I3 {
    foo(a: string, b: "y"): number;
    foo(a: "x", b: string): boolean;
    foo(a: string, b: string): any;
}